# Given a probability space (Ω,ℱ,P). Let F,G, and H be events such that (FG|H) = 1. Prove/disprove the following:

Tags: probability, statistics

I am having trouble with the following problem.

Given a probability space(Ω,ℱ,P). Let F,G, and H be events such that (FG|H) = 1. Prove/disprove the following:

(a) P(FG) = 1

(b) P(FGH) = P(H)

(c) P(F|H) = 0

I understand that part (b) can be proven using the given equation that (FG|H) = 1, where the conditional probability equation will convert the given equation to P(FGH)/P(H) = 1, which implies P(FGH) = P(H).

Could anyone provide guidance on how to go about proving/disproving Parts (a) and (c)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a take EP(FG|H)=1 and for c observe  P(H) = P(FGH) \leq P(FH) \leq P(H).